# using a list across different methods in c#

Tags: c#, winforms, list

I am reading a file into a list and then want a button to pull a random entry from the list. I can do this in VB but am fairly new to c#. I know I have to make the list public, but I'm getting increasingly frustrated.
The code below reads the file to a list and then a listbox.

```
namespace texttoarray
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int counter = 0;
            string line;
            var list = new List<string>();
            var file = new StreamReader(@"list.txt");
            while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                list.Add(line);
                counter++;
            }

            listBox2.DataSource = list;

            var rnd = new Random();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Any exception messages?

Comment: Could you please explain more on what you want to do?

Comment: call [code]int index = rnd.NextInt(0,list.count-1);[code] and use the returned number as index to get an entry from your list with [code]list[index];[code].

Comment: Just FYI: `static Random rnd`: `static` is not a valid modifier in the body of a method. It is valid only when you declare a member of a class (field, property, method...). I corrected it together with the reformatting of the whole code you've posted (included so many useless empty lines).

Comment: Variable `counter` is not needed, as the `list.Count` will do.

Comment: When using streams you should close the resource. The best way to do it would be using using(var file = new StreamReader(@"list.txt")){/* code that uses file*/}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to process some information inside one method and use this processed information inside another method, you can:

- pass the information as an argument to the second method
- keep the information inside your class and use it inside any method

I'll assume the second approach for you, so you can do something like this:

```
static class Program
{
    // list inside your class with the information you need
    private static List<string> fileLines;

    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // call the method to read your file and create the list
        FirstMethod();

        // second method to get a random line, in this case, will return the string
        var result = SecondMethod();

        Console.WriteLine(result);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static void FirstMethod()
    {
        // with this approach you can load one line per string inside your List<>
        var yourFile = File.ReadAllLines("C:\\test.txt");
        fileLines = new List<string>(yourFile);
    }

    private static string SecondMethod()
    {
        // random number starting with 0 and maximum to your list size
        var rnd = new Random();
        return fileLines[rnd.Next(0, fileLines.Count)];
    }
}
```